# replace empty cells by specific length in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to replace empty cells by certain count for each group in the data. Say data looks like the table below. In the first group, length of strings is 5 and hence row 3 should be filled with "NEW_STRING" across all 5 columns. However for group 2, length of strings is 3 and row 7 should be filled with "NEW_STRING" across the first 3 columns.

```
GROUP   | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 | col_5
------------------------------------------------
GROUP_1 | STR_1 | STR_2 | STR_3 | STR_4 | STR_5
GROUP_1 | STR_1 | STR_2 | STR_3 | STR_4 | STR_5
GROUP_1 |       |       |       |       |
GROUP_1 | STR_1 | STR_2 | STR_3 | STR_4 | STR_5
GROUP_2 | STR_1 | STR_2 | STR_3 |       |
GROUP_2 | STR_1 | STR_2 | STR_3 |       |
GROUP_2 |       |       |       |       |
```

Output should be like,

```
GROUP   | col_1  | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 | col_5
-------------------------------------------------
GROUP_1 | STR_1  | STR_2 | STR_3 | STR_4 | STR_5
GROUP_1 | STR_1  | STR_2 | STR_3 | STR_4 | STR_5
GROUP_1 | NEW_STR|NEW_STR|NEW_STR|NEW_STR|NEW_STR
GROUP_1 | STR_1  | STR_2 | STR_3 | STR_4 | STR_5
GROUP_2 | STR_1  | STR_2 | STR_3 |       |
GROUP_2 | STR_1  | STR_2 | STR_3 |       |
GROUP_2 | NEW_STR|NEW_STR|NEW_STR|       |
```

Kind help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: I'm still awaiting for the help!!! Kindly suggest.